# How to transpose columns with rows in DataFrame?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 1.6.0 and Java 7.

I've got the following input dataset:

```
ColumnName  Param1 Param2 Param3
Col1        P1      P2      P3
Col2        P2      P4      P5
Col3        P6      P2      P9
```

I'd like to transpose columns with rows so the above dataframe would look something like this with the column headers `ColumnName`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` (that initially were values under `ColumnName` column).

```
ColumnName  Col1    Col2    Col3
Param1      P1      P2      P6
Param2      P2      P4      P2
Param3      P3      P5      P9
```

Comment: Okay, still...tried to research anything? I've found a few examples already using SparkSQL

Comment: I don't have a solution other than "Google spark Dataframe transpose" because that's exactly what I just did (and you should before posting, preferably)

Comment: FRankly, most people come to SO for useful answers. We really don't mind whether the OP has done research as long as the question is clear. And this question is clear

Answer (score 0):

What about the following solution? (took me few hours to complete and feel a bit tired to make it prettier).

Given the following input:

```
val input = spark.
  read.
  option("header", true).
  option("delimiter", ",").
  csv("transpose.txt")
scala> input.show
+----------+------+------+------+
|ColumnName|Param1|Param2|Param3|
+----------+------+------+------+
|      Col1|    P1|    P2|    P3|
|      Col2|    P2|    P4|    P5|
|      Col3|    P6|    P2|    P9|
+----------+------+------+------+
```

I'd do the following to transpose columns with rows.

```
val fieldNames = input.schema.fieldNames
val cols = fieldNames.map(col(_))
val values = input.withColumn("values", struct(cols: _*))

val newCols = "ColumnName" +: input.select("ColumnName").as[String].collect
val fields = newCols.zipWithIndex.map { case (name, index) => input.schema(index).copy(name = name) }
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
val newSchema = StructType(fields)

val rows = input.drop("ColumnName").collect
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val newRows = fieldNames.
  drop(1).  // drop "ColumnName"
  zip(rows).
  map { case (f, r) => Row.merge(Row(f), r) }

val transposed = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(newRows), newSchema)
```

The result seems to match the requirement:

```
scala> transposed.show
+----------+----+----+----+
|ColumnName|Col1|Col2|Col3|
+----------+----+----+----+
|    Param1|  P1|  P2|  P3|
|    Param2|  P2|  P4|  P5|
|    Param3|  P6|  P2|  P9|
+----------+----+----+----+
```

Now the question is how effective it is (if at all)? It *just* works with a small dataset.

Answer (score 0):

We've `pivot` function to perform the same.

`Java` version:

```
Input:
+---------------+-------------+------+-------+
|       SensorId|   SensorName| Value|   Unit|
+---------------+-------------+------+-------+
|              1|     Humidity|    57|      p|
|              2|  Temperature|    25|      c|
|              1|     Humidity|    62|      p|
|              2|  Temperature|    27|      c|
|              1|     Humidity|    60|      p|
+---------------+-------------+------+-------+

df.groupBy("Sensor_Id","Unit")
  .pivot("SensorName").min("Value");

Output:
+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+
|       SensorId|         Unit| Humidity| Temperature|
+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+
|              1|            p|       57|        null|
|              2|            c|     null|          25|
|              1|            p|       62|        null|
|              2|            c|     null|          27|
|              1|            p|       60|        null|
+---------------+-------------+------+---------------+
```